# Java recursively populate a Object

Tags: java

I have a json which is a list of objects with a property of its own type (property manager is of type employee) as below.

```
  {
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": "",
      "address": {
        "city": "",
        "state": ""
      },
      "manager": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "address": {
          "city": "",
          "state": ""
        },
        "manager": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have DTO classes with below properties where Employee has a member variable of type Employee.

```
class Employee{
    private String id;
    priavte Address address;
    private Employee manager
    //getter & setter
}
class Address{
    private String city;
    //getter & setter
}
```

My requirement is to populate Employee Object recursively (nesting can be of n level `Employee -> Manager -> Manager -> Manager ...`) and form a new List of Employee Object.

Which will give us the result as below

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": ""
      "address": {
        "city": ""
      },
      "manager": {
        "id": ""
        "address": {
          "city": ""
        },
        "manager": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: What do you mean by "populate Employee object"? Note that if you want to get all the employee bosses you just need a loop.

Comment: Here requirement  is to insert (populate Employee object with their manager and manger of manger )all employee's manager. @Traik

Comment: Add an array of employees to employee class. Use a while loop to go through managers. Do your homework man. That's the way to learn. When it will be time to work, you will be alone in front of the keyboard.

Comment: Thnaks for the suggestion @Tarik, but the requirement is different here. This Employee class represent a SQL Table with self join to get the relation of all employee and their managers

Comment: The hierarchical structure is a tree. However, if you go up the tree you end up with a list. All you need is to loop.

Comment: Make a map for employee id as key and employee as value and recursively populate the the data per employee call by id then for there manager do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the way to achieve the solution of above problem

```
private List<Employee> mapEmployeeModel(List<Employee> employeeList, List<Employee> newEmployeeList) {

        for (Employee emp : employeeList) {
            Employee newEmp = mapEmployee(emp);
            newEmployeeList.add(newEmp);
        }
        
        return newEmployeeList;
}
    
private Employee mapEmployee(Employee emp) {
        
        Employee newEmp = new Employee ();
        newEmp.setId(emp.getId());
        newEmp.setName(emp.getName());
        newEmp.setAddress(mapAddress(emp));
        if(emp.getManager() == null) {
            return newEmp;          
        } else {
            newEmp.setManager(mapEmployee(emp.getManager()));// Recursively setting up the managers
        }
        
        return newEmp;
        
}
    

private Address mapAddress(Employee emp) {
        
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCity(emp.getAddress().getCity);      
        return address;
}
```